# How did I solve SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS issue for Java beans?

Tags: java, json, spring

I was writing code for my project in my current role using Spring MVC architecture. My code was to

1. Make a POST REST WebService call to thirds party vendor
2. Get the XML response back as XML
3. Parse the XML response and
4. Put it in a DataBase table column

I was able to code and test until point 3 above but not able to test point 4 as once the data is inserted and retrieved from DB, the Spring MVC architecture started throwing below error:

```
[http-nio-8080-exec-5] ERROR c.t.dl4.restapi.APIExceptionMapper - No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["responseData"]->org.json.simple.JSONObject["javaBean"]->org.json.simple.JSONObject["coulmnName"]->org.json.simple.JSONObject["xmlNode"])
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.json.JSONObject and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: java.util.HashMap["responseData"]->org.json.simple.JSONObject["javaBean"]->org.json.simple.JSONObject["coulmnName"]->org.json.simple.JSONObject["xmlNode"])
```

After debugging I found the issue and it was a simple casting mistake that I forgot to consider while doing the coding.

Code with the bug is below:

```
if(RESPONSE.has("xmlNode") && !RESPONSE.get("xmlNode").equals("")) {
                columenMap.put("xmlNode", RESPONSE.getJSONObject("xmlNode"));
            }
```

The issue was I was trying to cast **org.json.JSONObject** object to **org.json.simple.JSONObject** and this caused the failure.

The solution was to parse the value from **org.json.JSONObject** and then cast it to use as **org.json.simple.JSONObject**.

The fixed/updated code is below:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

if(RESPONSE.has("xmlNode") && !RESPONSE.get("xmlNode").equals("")) {
    org.json.simple.JSONObject xmlNodeObj = (org.json.simple.JSONObject) parser.parse(RESPONSE.getJSONObject("xmlNode").toString());

    columenMap.put("xmlNode", xmlNodeObj);
            }
```

And this fixed the SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS issue.

Thanks.